# Hibernate delete from onetomany

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables with OneToMany relation

> class ServiceProvider {
>
> ...
>
> @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="serviceProvider",
>             cascade={CascadeType.ALL,CascadeType.REMOVE},orphanRemoval = true)
>     @OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)    private
>   List serviceCenters; ...
>
> }
>
> class ServiceCenterDetails {
>
> ...   //bi-directional many-to-one association to
>   ServiceProviderDomainMap  @ManyToOne
>     @JoinColumn(name="SERVICE_PROVIDER_ID")     private ServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider;
>
> ...
>
> }

I am trying to delete provide row.  But i am getting below error:

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fixoline`.`service_center_details`, CONSTRAINT `FK_qvahoxeovx9vmwl6mcu2c0lyw` FOREIGN KEY (`SERVICE_PROVIDER_ID`) REFERENCES `service_provider` (`ID`))

below is the way i am trying

> ```
>   String hql = "DELETE FROM ServiceProvider WHERE id =  :providerId";
>   Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
>           query.setParameter("providerId",providerId);
>
>   int result = query.executeUpdate();
> ```

could someone pls help resolving it?

Answer (score 3):

There are two tings,

1. Why you are using `@OnDelete` when you using `CascadeType.ALL` in `@oneToMany`? `CascadeType.ALL` will delete child entities when parent is deleted.
2. `@OnDelete` mainly used in child entities with `@ManyToOne` not otherwise.

Try with any option and check.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear: There are foreign key references to the `ServiceProvider`s you are trying to delete. Delete `ServiceCenterDetails` first:

```
delete from ServiceCenterDetails where serviceProvider.id = :providerId
```

Comment: Sadly i do not have any rows in ServiceCenterDetails  table.  Is there anything else that can go wrong

Comment: The exception says otherwise. Do you maybe insert them in the same transaction in which you delete `ServiceProvider`s?

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

this exception tells that you should delete your ServiceCenterDetails associated with ServiceProviders first and then delete the ServiceProviders.