# Spring + Hibernate :Unable to delete child in unidirectional relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

i tried finding similar issue here and i found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436982/hibernate-unable-to-delete-child-record)
but it did not help much.

this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831438/hibernate-delete-from-onetomany) is the exact issue i have. Thing is the @OnDelete forces me to make a bidirectional relationship right? I would like to keep it unidirectional if possible.

What i want to do is delete a comment (child) from a post (parent);

every time i am trying to do that i receive this error

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blogapp2`.`post_comments`, CONSTRAINT `FKrvgf8o4dg5kamt01me5gjqodf` FOREIGN KEY (`comments_id`) REFERENCES `comment` (`id`))
```

this is my code
the delete method

```
  @GetMapping("/dashboard/showposts/deletecomment/{id}")
    public String deleteComment(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        commentService.deleteComment(id);
        return "redirect:/admin/dashboard/showposts";
    }
```

in Post

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

in Comment there is no reference to the Parent.
How can i delete the Comment from the database? i mention that cascade works with no issues so when i delete the parent all the children are deleted aswell.
Any help would be greatly appreciated !

**L.E:I modified my handler method to look like this**

```
 @GetMapping("/dashboard/showposts/deletecomment/{id}")
    public String deleteComment(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        List<Comment> comments = commentService.findAll();
        Comment comment = commentService.findBYId(id);
        comments.remove(comment);
        return "redirect:/admin/dashboard/showposts";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without creating bidirectional relationship but there is one caveat in doing so and I would come to that later, let's see how you can do that in unidirectional relationship.

First you need to specify the `orphanRemoval=true` on your entity relation

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList();

// Now I am assuming you have equals and hash code methods are implemented in your comment class,

// So all you need to load the Comment Entity by its id and then have to call

Comment comment = dao.findById(id);
comments.remove(comment);

// This will delete the comment from table and will keep all comments as it is.

// Another way is to iterate the comments list and find matching Comment object (add the method in transaction)

@Service
class PostService {

    @Transactional
    public Comment deleteComment(Integer commentId) {
       Post post = repository.findById(id);
       List<Comment> comments = post.getComments();
       Comment comment = comments.stream().filter(c -> c.getId().equals(commentId)).findAny()
     .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid comment id"));
      
      comments.remove(comment);

      return comment;
    }

}
```

Caveats:

```
1. post.getComments() // will load all comments from database
2. comments.remove(comment) // will trigger additional INSERT statements
```

Why additional insert statements will be triggered?

When you use uni-directional mapping, JPA provider (hibernate) will create additional junction table and your relation becomes `@ManyToMany` at the background.

So it will first Delete all the entries from junction table passing associated `post_id` and then insert all the records back to junction table, leaving the record we deleted.

Then it will delete the entry from comment table, so its a performance penalty you have to pay using unidirectional relation.

Comment: ok, so i have edited my op with how i have modified my handler so far.Is this method correct?. Do i absolutely need to implement hashcode and equals for this to work? since right now i don't have them implemented and it seems it does not remove my comment from the comments list.

Comment: did you add `orphanRemoval=true` to your entity mapping and please check your equals and hascode implementation, best way to check in your code itself to check like `System.out.println(comments.contains(comment))`, if it gives true then your implementation is correct and it should delete the object, one thing you might be missing is transaction, if you have commonService under transaction this will not work.

Comment: ok i implemented hashcode and equals (intellij default for all fields, is this ok? ) but it still does not remove the comment. When i use the print statement i receive true in the console.What is commonService? how can i check if i have that?

Comment: What is your CommentService a repository or service?

Comment: a Service class. i also have a CommentRepository wich extends CrudRepository

Comment: Ok check my answer, I have written `PostService` example which you can use and let me know if it works or not, also make sure you have `orphanRemoval = true` on your mapping.

Comment: it works, thanks alot ! But what is the deal with @Transactional ? why it works now but id didn't before?

Comment: In simple terms you can think of it as a boundary or a unit of work, so all operation performed inside it commits or all fails even when one operation fails, so every operation requires transaction, by default spring jpa repository methods are transactional, so in earlier example, when you fetched the entity, transaction is committed and you were doing the operation outside it, so transaction manager is not aware of this operation and you are playing around with simple java objects, nothing happened in db, its little difficult to explain in very simple terms for me but you can read about it.

Answer (score 0):

By the error message, I assume that besides tables `post` and `comments`, you have a join table named `post_comments`.

If thats the case, hibernate is not aware of it. You should use not only `@OneToMany` but `@JoinTable` annotation as well in the `comments`field of `Post` class.

Comment: i have modified that field like this ```@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();``` and i still get the same issue